# Sun and Moon meditation according to Swaminaraya Vachanamrut Ahmedabad 1

Tags: meditation, swaminarayan

Vachnamrut link
https://www.swaminarayangadi.com/publications/book.php?pid=143&sid=273&cid=4899

I have did my R&D online. And have not found anything useful.

Can someone with good knowledge help me here?
Also, is there anyone done this type of meditation.

1. Does this meditation mentioned in Valmiki Ramayana? (I have found on article on speaking tree but it is now removed or modified)
2. How to do it proper?
3. Can anyone explain in detail how to do it?
4. What is the meaning of visualize god inside jiva and how to do it in visualization?
5. What preparation should I do to do this meditation?
6. What time is best to do this meditation?
7. How many times can we it per day and what is minimum time duration per seating?

Thanks in advance.